# Complete or Completed with present tense or future tense

Tags: grammar

> End of the day if it **will not complete** tell me
>   End of the day if it **will not completed** tell me
>   End of the day if it **is not complete** tell me
>   End of the day if it **is not completed** tell me

Which one is correct.

Comment: As it stands, this question is meaningless. None of these sequences represents a "correct" sentence, and we don't know what exactly the OP wants to say. It's currently Not Constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All are grammatically incorrect. They have to be either:

> If, *at the end of the day*, it **will not be completed**, (please) tell me (now).

or

> If it **will not be completed** *at the end of the day*, tell me (now).

or

> If it **is not completed** *at the end of the day*, tell me (before you go home).